# Most simple polymorphism example in OCaml?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, sample

I am very new to OCaml. Can you please give me the most simple example of polymorphism in OCaml which newbie can understand? I know Java, C# and C++ and also have some sense about functional languages.

Answer (score 5):

The identity is polymorphic:

```
let id x = x
```

Comment: Pls add some explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple example of a polymorphic function in OCaml:

```
let rec length = function
| [] -> 0
| _ :: tail -> 1 + length tail
```

This function calculates the length of any list. In other words, it's fully polymorphic in the type of the things in the list. This kind of polymorphism is called parametric, to distinguish it from the more OO kind of "ad hoc" polymorphism (as in Java) where polymorphism is achieved by giving different implementations for different cases. With parametric polymorphism there's just one implementation that works across many types. Of course, OCaml also has OO-style polymorphism. And Java has a kind of parametric polymorphism called "generics".

Comment: Since the SO appears to be new to type inference, wouldn't it be a good idea to also show the types for this example and explain how 'a types are generic. :)

Comment: I thought this might be too much detail, but I'm happy to add this info :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the classical OO "bad example" of adhoc polymorphism that Jeffrey was talking about in case you are interested:

```
class virtual animal = object
  method virtual say : unit
end

class dog = object
  inherit animal
  method say = print_endline "bark"
end

class cat = object
  inherit animal
  method say = print_endline "meow"
end

let my_animals = [new dog; new cat]

let () = List.iter (fun x -> x#say) my_animals
```

Comment: eww, showing object and classes to a beginner... One may be lead to believe that OCaml is an OOP language!

Comment: I hear `Obj.magic` is pretty polymorphic as well. Maybe you should explain that one in another answer for completeness ;)